# Adding not existing key to dictionary with if statement (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'd like to know, how I could check if a key already exists in a dictionary. I am using the following code:

```py
my_dict = {};
my_list = ["one", "two", "three", "one"];
for i in my_list:
    if i in my_dict: 
        continue;
    else:
       my_dict[i] = 0;
```

but I'd like to use "NOT" operator in if statement to remove else operator from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
my_dict = {}
my_list = ["one", "two", "three", "one"]
for i in my_list:
    if i not in my_dict:
       my_dict[i] = 0
```

Thus, it will only add the value if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me.

Comment: I tried to use "!" Operator in if statement and it didn't work, I forgot about operator "not" :((.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
if i not in my_dict:
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(my_list, 0)
```